# a pointer to `std::list` of Eigen datas

Tags: c++, opengl, std, eigen3

I'm using Eigen3 2-dimensional vector as 2D point for opengl drawing, storing them in a list:

```
typedef Eigen::Vector2d Vec2D;
std::list<Vec2D> points;
```

Now, I need an array of GLfloat to pass the entire data structure of raw float coordinate value to the graphic card:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

_vertex = new GLfloat[points.size()*2];
_colors = new GLfloat[points.size()*4];

std::list<Vec2D>::const_iterator it;
int i=0, j=0;
for(it=points.begin(); it!=points.end(); ++it) {
    _vertex[i] = it->x()+2;
    _vertex[i+1] = it->y()+2;
    i+=2;

    _colors[j] = getRed(j/4.0f, it);
    _colors[j+1] = getGreen(j/4.0f, it);
    _colors[j+2] = getBlue(j/4.0f, it);
    _colors[j+3] = getAlpha(j/4.0f, it);
    j+=4;
}

glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, _colors);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, _vertex);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, points.size());

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

delete _vertex;
delete _colors;
```

Is there a more efficent way for creating the arrays to pass to the graphic cards? like pass `points.begin()` and find out what is the offset and avoid to loop through all the points?

I mean.. in the memory the x and y coordinates of the `Eigen::Vector2d` has to be stored in some consecutive space.. so.. I think I can pass it directly to the graphic card.. but I can't unserstand how.

Comment: You need a custom gl buffer ?

Comment: what sorry? I need - from opengl documentation of `glVertexPointer`: __a pointer to the first coordinate of the first vertex in the array.__

Comment: I have also changed the title of the answer, hope a bit more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::list does not hold it's data in contiguous memory, you need std::vector for that(or std::array if you know the size at compile time, but you probably don't). Vector has a method data() which returns a pointer to underlying data. However if you store internally Eigen::vec2d you can't pass it to openGl, since it's a dynamic structure and your data will be all over your memory. You need structure that keeps data in place(and btw is more readable than vec2d, which is kinda odd in this context). For example:

```
struct VertexData
{
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat red;
    GLfloat green;
    GLfloat blue;
    GLfloat alpha;    
}
```

And then use glVertexPointer to pass it to openGL using sizeof(VertexData) as stride

To delete new'ed arrays you need to use

```
delete [] _vertex;
```

normal delete will only free the first element. Or even better, you could use smart pointers, std::unique_ptr would be best in this case

```
std::unique_ptr<GLfloat[]> _vertex(new GLfloat[points.size() * sizeof(GLfloat)]);
```

It will automatically free the memory when it goes out of scope(at the end of the block)

Comment: thank you for the answer. but.. can you provide me a minimal exemplify snippet for the smart pointer or the delete? and what about eigen memory? i think Vec2D probb has some offest.. how find it out?

Comment: Maybe `sizeof(Vec2D)!=2*sizeof(GLfloat)` indeed. You can check it out with a cout. If so, you'll need to use `sizeof(Vec2D)` as the `stride` in your gl calls, otherwise even with `.data()` it won't work.

Comment: Vec2D is probably dynamic, and therefore you can't just pass a bunch of those to ogl. I edited my answer

Comment: Vec2D is based on Eigen3 vectors, where everything is based on template parameters. So not dynamic (if by that you means pointer attributes). With an `offset` and `stride`, it should work fine.

Comment: I checked Eigen docs and vector2d is just a funny way of saying 'pair of doubles'. So you could use it with glVertexPointer, but i think a custom struct would give away your intentions better.

Comment: how can I test it? I mean, how can I write a function with the same API `glTest(num_data_to_read, type, stride, raw_array);`? just with pointer increment `type *it = raw_array; ... it+=sizeof(stride)` ?

Answer (score 2):

`points` is a `std::list` so it doesn't contain an contiguous array of data.

If you use `std::vector` instead however, then in C++11 you can access the array used internally with `points.data()`. This means you don't need `_vertex` anymore.

Know that, as an alternative, you can even go further and have a class (named for instance `Vertex`) which contains both the vertex position and its color and then use the `data()` method on your `std::vector<Vertex>` in combination with [`glInterleavedArrays`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glInterleavedArrays.xml) (with `stride=sizeof(Vertex)`).

Comment: why not `glDrawArrays`? is does also let me specify the offset/stride.. Antway, thansk. Your voice is to use a custom struct instead of `Eigen::vector2d`..

Comment: Yes, you can achieve the same thing with multiple `glDrawArrays` calls, I didn't want to get into that to keep the answer simple though. :) Honestly, custom struct or not, it really depends on what you want to do with the colors here. However try to get rid of `new/delete` in your code one way or another, like aryjczyk said. In your example, you could have for instance typed the 2 _.. arrays as `std::vector<GLfloat>` or `std::unique_ptr<GLfloat[]>` instead of raw `GLfloat*` pointers.